# Load JS library from another JS library, and let the page use it

Tags: javascript, html

For my purposes, I want to be able to load a JavaScript library (file1.js) from the HTML page (file.html) and within file1.js, load file2.js. I then want file2.js's functions to be able to run in file.html without loading it directly from file.html.

Also, file1.js successfully loads from file.html, and file2.js successfully loads from file1.js. However, file2.js's functions can't be accessed in file.html. How would I do this?

This is my code:

file.html:

```
<script src="../path/to/file1.js">
functionFromFile2(); // This doesn't work!
</script>
```

file1.js:

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = "../path/to/file2.js";
script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = init1;
document.head.appendChild(script);

var init1 = function() {
  functionFromFile2(); // This works!
}
```

file2.js

```
function functionFromFile2() {
  // code...
}
```

How can I get functionFromFile2() working in file.html? Btw, this question is out of context and this setup IS REQUIRED - I can't combine the 2 files. I also don't want to reference file2.js from file.html, because the path of file2.js can change, and both file.html and file1.js use functions from file2.js.

I don't NEED dynamic imports, however, if I can use a dynamic import, then I can keep the single line in file.html, which is the goal, to keep it as just one line. I know that it's not needed in this example, but that's because it's an example and in my actual version it's required.

I require vanilla JavaScript. No libraries, please! I'm sure that there's some kind of library that will do what I want, but I want to keep my project %100 vanilla.

Comment: what is your justification for not wanting to include both js files within `file.html`? `"I can't combine the 2 files..."`; why?

Comment: Because file2.js is a library that both myself and others can use, (but file1.js isn't) and file1.js is a script that uses the library and also gets used across multiple webpages on my site, and copying the massive block of text that is the actual script would be idiotic when I can just have 1 version of it and reference the script.

Comment: Does that answer your question?

Comment: Oh, also, file.html uses the library as well, but it doesn't use it in the same way as any other webpage.

Comment: I have thought long and hard about many alternatives, but none of them are very convenient, like having 2 source tags. It would just be nice to have 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you want javascript "includes" :) Which is probably not forseen. But you could come to the idea to fetch the script source by ajax. Write a tiny pre processor which loads other files, combine them whatever. At this moment its just text and then either add a new script object to the dom like you are thinking of or simply evaluate the final  string. Which will also make all functions and variables availeable.

```
                function GetText(url, fkt) {
                var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
                        return this.responseText;
                    }
                }
                xhttp.open("GET", url, false);
                xhttp.send();
                if (typeof fkt === 'undefined') {
                    return xhttp.responseText;
                } else {
                    return fkt(xhttp.responseText);
                }
            }
```

this will get you any kind of file in return. You can also add a function to do something with the file inside the script; 
and now we just do a

```
     var src=GetText("../js/script2.js");
     eval(src);
```

or

```
     var dynamicURL ="./js/startrek.js"

     var src=GetText(dynamicURL);
     eval(src);
```

Note that the scope of the eval can be limited also to objects.
As you can see you can change the script location also variable.
See also this nice tutorial [Dynamic add scripts](https://www.xul.fr/javascript/eval.php)

Comment: Will this allow me to access code from file2.js in file.html, when file2.js was loaded in file1.js?

Comment: yes put this routine either inside the html or inside file1.js. just has t be ready before using it. Now you can run the function from html or from your file1.js

Comment: I'll look into this. Seems promising.

Comment: BTW this code even it is ajax is not really asynchron. After the eval call everything is fine and loaded. No fancy events etc. put in the html file the call to the first js file directly before the body end tag. and in the init routine which you calls from the html on load you call this things from me. Then just eval them and all you want to have is seen and ready in the html. Keep things simple :)

Comment: So I have to put eval(src) in file.html as well as in file1.js, right?

Comment: no just at least before you want to uses those functions from file 2 first times. I would load them as soon i can from your file1.js

Comment: no just *before* you want to use the functions from file 2 I would put the call to the init routine of file1.js. That is the function you call from your html onload first.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use a custom event. this way you can let your code in the HTML know when your file was loaded in file1.

[Link to example code](http:///https://codepen.io/Jscherbe/pen/BaBrvRJ)

**Example (timeout for simulating file1)**

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Pretending to be File1 (Aysnc Stuff)
  (function() {
    function init() {
      console.log('The file loaded, creating an event to let the document know')
      var fileReadyEvent = new CustomEvent('file2ready');
      document.dispatchEvent(fileReadyEvent);
    }
    setTimeout(init, 2000);
  })();
  
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    function doStuff() {
      console.log('Im doing stuff');
    }
    document.addEventListener('file2ready', doStuff);
  })();
  
</script>
```

*Note: Custom events are not supported in old internet explorer so a polyfill would be needed to support ancient browsers. Also if you are using jquery it has/had custom events with trigger(), and on().*

Comment: I don't care about old browsers.

Comment: Yes unless that code wasn't exposed to the window (functions wrapped in a function). It is basically the same thing as your init function except in your example file1 is the only one that knows when the script has finished loading. So by creating the event you can let your code (in the HTML) that file1 has done it's job and everything should be ready,

Comment: The first block goes in file1.js and the second block goes in file.html, right? Where do I add the URL to file2.js?

Comment: I was assuming that the issue you are having isn't the scope of the functions within file2 but how to get the code in the document (HTML) to fire when file2 has been loaded/evaluated/available which only File1 knows.

Comment: You only need to add this to your init function to fire the event. Not the timeout.

var fileReadyEvent = new CustomEvent('file2ready');
document.dispatchEvent(fileReadyEvent);

Comment: I'll look into this, although it does require more than 1 line in file.html.